# Windows Authentication login modal not accepting credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, active-directory, windows-authentication

I am having an ASP.NET website running under Windows Authentication.The issue I am facing is that I can't get pass from login screen while submitting my credentials:

[image]

I have the following settings in IE:

"Enable Integrated Windows Authentication" checkbox is checked.

[image]

"Automatic logon with current username and password" radio button is selected.

[image]

IIS authentication is set to "Windows Authentication":

[image]

My web.config is having:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
      <authorization>
         <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
```

The provider for that authentication is set to "NTLM"

[image]

AppPoolIdentity is set to "NetworkService"

I have even given "Full rights" to "Everyone" role to my website.

I have confirmed the user with which I am trying to login exists in Windows Active directory:

[image]

In order to debug the cause I attached the process to source and I noticed that I was able to reach Application_BeginRequest but the breakpoints I added in PreRequestHandlerExecute handler could not reach, may be thrown out in between to login modal again.

Can you help me locating the cause of windows login modal not accepting my credentials?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting IIS? I had a similar issue isn't the past.

Comment: I have restarted the IIS, no success :(

Comment: I'll check my confit when I get to work. But I think you look good. Are you sure your credentials are ok? What browser are you using for your app?

Comment: Got the fix by following registry solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/24333926

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the Internet Zone.  Add an entry to the Intranet zone for your web site.