# Calls from an MVC Web Application to a Web API on the same IIS server returns "401 Unauthorized"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have an API and web application hosted on the same IIS server. When I try to execute an API method inside the server, it returns "401 unauthorized". When I try to execute an API method outside the server (while debugging) it works just fine. I'm using NTLM authentication for the API.

UPDATE: This is working when I disable NTLM authentication but having it (NTLM) enabled is one of the requirements. :(

Please help me. :(

Comment: Sounds reasonable - server-to-server would usually come with app pool account credentials which unlikely to be authorized by your WebAPI service. Not really sure if you expect it to work...

Comment: So are you saying that I can't have my web api and web application inside the same IIS server?

Comment: To add, this is working before I enabled NTLM authentication. The problem starts when I enabled it. Need your advise guys if what I'm trying to do is feasible. :(

Comment: I think you may find some guidance here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107044/401-unauthorized-error-web-api-mvc-windows-authentication

Comment: Thanks selganor. I'll read it. :)